# Persistent vs non-Persistent - Which should I use?

Tags: mysql

My site has always used persistent connections, based on my understanding of them there's no reason not to.  Why close the connection when it can be reused?  I have a site that in total accesses about 7 databases.  It's not a huge traffic site, but it's big enough.  What's your take on persistent, should I use them?

Comment: All connections can fail, and the server can time them out. You therefore have to be able to cope with having to create a new connection: so you may as well use a connection pool, instead of relying on heroic assumptions about connection longevity that aren't true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With persistent connections:

- You cannot build transaction processing effectively
- impossible user sessions on the same connection
- app are not scalable. With time you may need to extend it and it will require management/tracking of persistent connections
- if the script, for whatever reason,  could not release the lock on the table, then any following scripts will block indefinitely and one should restart the db server. Using transactions, transaction block will also pass to the next script (using the same connection) if script execution ends before the transaction block completes, etc.

Persistent connections do not bring anything you can do with non-persistent connections.
Then, why to use them, at all?
The only possible reason is performance, to use them when overhead of creating a link to your SQL Server is high. And this depends on many factors like:

- database type
- whether MySQl server is on the same machine and, if not, how far? might be out of your local network /domain?
- how much overloaded by other processes the machine on which MySQL sits

One always can replace persistent connections with non-persistent connections. It might change the performance of the script, but not its behavior!

Commercial RDMS might be licensed by the number of concurrent opened connections and here the persistent connections can misserve

Comment: +1 for the info on MySql not being free for commercial use.  I wonder how many people don't realize this.  Although, a paid for license is pretty cheap.

Comment: crap I didn't know that... I'll have to look into that, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way I can track the overhead of establishing/closing connections ?  I get errors involving too many connections so I'm wondering if persistent is part of the problem.  When you say transactions what do you mean, just queries?

Comment: I am MSSQLServer/C# dev. I just used in the past MySql occasionally from C#. I answered as database dev, not as PHP one. Your question (to measure overhead) is basically a different question and it is PHP question. Post a new question on it because I was already banned for having discussions (it is not a discussion forum). AFAIK, overhead is negligible in most typical cases. If you have errors due to too many connections, what other choice do you have, anyway?

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask a new question

Comment: @GennadyVaninГеннадийВанин, Aren't all of the four points you mentioned above fixed by [mysqli's implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) already? What exactly do you mean when you say "app are not scalable"?

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge on the area is kinda limited so I can't give you many details on the subject but, as far as I know, the process of creating connections and handing them to a thread really costs resources, so I would avoid it if I were you. Anyhow I think that most of this decisions can't be generalized and depend on the business.

If, for instance, your application communicates continuously with the Database and will only stop when the application is closed, then perhaps persistent connections are the way to go, for you avoid the process mentioned before.

However, if your application only communicates with the Database sporadically to get minor information then closing the connection might be more sane, for you won't waste resources on opened connections that are not being used.

Also there is a technique called "Connection Pooling", in which you create a series of connections a priori and keep them there for other applications to consume. In this case connections are persistent to the database but non-persistent to the applications.

Note: Connections in MSSQL are always persistent to the database because connection pooling is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Non-persistent**

> The non-persistent connection takes a total time of 2RTT + file
> transmission time. It takes the first RTT (round-trip time) to
> establish the connection between the server and the client. The second
> RTT is taken to request and return the object. This case stands for a
> single object transmission.
> After the client receives the object in non-persistent, the connection is immediately closed. This is the basic difference
> between persistent and non-persistent. The persistent connection
> ensures the transfer of ​multiple objects over a single connection.

**Persistent**

> A persistent connection takes 1 RTT for the connection and then
> transfers as many objects, as wanted, over this single connection.
> RTT stands for the round-trip time taken for an object request and then its retrieval. In other words, it is the time
> taken to request the object from the client to the server and then
> retrieve it from the server back to the client.

Suppose 10 images need to be downloaded from the HTTP server. The total time taken to request and download 10 images in a non-persistent and persistent connection is:

> ```
> 2 RTT (Connection time) + 2 * 10 RTT= 22RTT (Non-persistent)
>
> 2 RTT (Connection time) + 10 RTT= 12RTT (Persistent)
> ```

can visit:
https://www.educative.io/answers/non-persistent-vs-persistent-http

On the bases of  performance  should use persistence connection

**BUT**

With persistence connection: 1)scalability of apps are not, 2) With time you may need to extend it and it will require management/tracking of persistent connections, 3) cannot build transaction processing effectively, 4) impossible user sessions on the same connection....
You can not do with persistence connection which can do with non-persistence connection.

Note: Connections in MSSQL are always persistent to the database because connection pooling is the default behavior.

Then,  why use that.