# AWS RDS MySQL connection with AWS Lambda

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to deploy a mobile application back-end application in aws lambda service. But I need to clarify few things.
In most examples I found in internet have all three steps,

- Create connection
- Execute query
- Close connection

But according to my feel this is a huge overhead to the MySQL database. Is there any best practice to handle these connections? Or should I move to EC2 instances for hosting the application?

Comment: maybe this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765925/persistent-vs-non-persistent-which-should-i-use. Using Lambda or EC-2 again depends on your budget and features you need

Comment: My app is a content management system. All rest calls has a database access. I think that lambda is not suitable for my app. Do you agree with me?

Comment: AWS announced the ability for Lambda functions to access VPC resources (like RDS MySQL) at re:Invent 2015 this year, but that feature is not available at this time.  Without this you'll need to put your database on the public internet which is generally a bad idea.  Besides this limitation Lambda is likely a good fit for you your described use case.  Currently Lambda works very nicely with DynamoDB since that service is on the public internet so you may want to look at that as an alternative to MySQL.

Comment: Remembering that MySQL grew up along with CGI, Perl, PHP, and one new connection per web page load...  frequent connection establishment is certainly not without cost, but probably does not represent the overhead you anticipate, so your best bet is to try it and see.

Comment: @JaredHatfield, I have some rich queries which are hard to do with DynamoDB. Therefore I selected MySQL. Also I think it is cheap than DynamoDB.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot , I got what are you saying now. I'll try to use Lambda.